# Прокручивание страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как узнать куда я прокручиваю страницу - вверх или вниз?

Answer (score 3):

Можно добавить обработчик события `scroll` для `window`, в котором сравнивать текущий сдвиг (`.scrollTop()`) с сохранённым предыдущим значением:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $window = $(window);
    var prevOffset = $window.scrollTop();
    $window.on("scroll", function(e) {
        var newOffset = $window.scrollTop();
        var change = newOffset - prevOffset;
        if (change > 0) {
            console.log("Down");
        }
        else if (change < 0) {
            console.log("Up");
        }
        prevOffset = newOffset;
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```